# Create a plot from boxplot.stats

Tags: r, plotly, boxplot

Someone sent me a file containing the list of *boxplot.stats*.
I now want to reproduce and plot this *boxplot* from the list. (I have stats, n , conf and out).

How should I proceed? Can I use plotly for this purpose?

So I have the following list

`stats
[1] -0.30518460  0.08578944  0.28487839  0.34645644  0.73711925`

`n
[1] 3472096`

`conf
[1] 0.2846574 0.2850994`

`out
[1] -2.5168701 -0.3115725  0.7683801  1.9771345 -0.5612497 -1.0996948`

And my output should be boxplot with the values above.

Comment: Please provide an example of your data along with the expected output

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by `boxplot.stats` you mean the `list` of values `boxplot` normally produces, you can use `bxp` to plot.

```
x <- boxplot(rnorm(100))
bxp(x)
```

The `boxplot.stats` function does the computation for `boxplot`, but doesn't work with `bxp` directly.

```
bxp(boxplot.stats(rnorm(100)))
Error in z$stats[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions
```

If you do just have the output from `boxplot.stats`, you can hack out a solution by converting each of the list elements to a 1 column matrix:

```
bxp(lapply(boxplot.stats(rnorm(100)),as.matrix,1))
```

Comment: Yes, your are right, i mean the `list` of values  `boxplot` produces. And I want to use the second error like you, What do I have to do, I am  confused.

Comment: I have the values saved in a list, i.e. boxlist is my list with the values above. And I get `bxp(boxlist)
Error in z$stats[, i] : incorrect number of dimensions`, but you have already said that this is not possible

Comment: @Jensxy You can do it, but it is a bit hacky, see the edit.

Comment: but then i only have the outliers, right?

Comment: Sorry i mean I only have the stats and not the outliers

Comment: You need a group element in the list, `c(lapply(yourlist,as.matrix,1),group=1)`